# Crystal Reports web viewer not using system date format

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Hi I have a crystal report but it will not use the date format of the computer.

I have already changed the sShortDate format to dd/MM/yyyy for all users in registry. The report is still  showing US date formats. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click on your Field
2. Select Formate Object
3. Select Date and Time Tab
4. Chose the format what you want.

Comment: I want the format to be dependent on the computers system settings. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: Hi. How did you get this to work please I am struggling to display anything except a load error. VS2013 IIS8 Windows 2012 Server. SQL 2012. Works in designer. Doesn't work when deployed.